# Loading external page and replace some it's attributes using python

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In my project I'm trying to access some of specific route in some external page.
The route controlled by java script (i.e
[you get two drop-down menu, that controls the categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykZqk.png)
)

so far my code looks like this - and it product list of links of the first page:

```
def getAllIndexOfStringInPage(string):
read =requests.get("https://example.com/").text
res = [i for i in range(len(read)) if read.startswith(string, i)]
return res, read

def getAllLinks():
html1 = getAllIndexOfStringInPage("a href")
html2 = getAllIndexOfStringInPage("target=\"_blank\">my condition in the tag")
extractedLinks = []
c = -1
    for startIndex in html1[0]:
    c += 1
    f = html1[1][startIndex:html2[0][c]]
    extractedLinks.append(f.replace("amp;", ""))

c = 0
for link in extractedLinks:
    extractedLinks[c] = "https" + (link.split("&sp=r")[0] + "&sp=r").split("http")[1]
    c += 1

return extractedLinks
```

the path in the page I want to change is the following -
[option value =0 redirects the page to get all of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzJ9B.png)
I wish to change the value of the option from 0 to 1 to 7xx

I did some research and I found the library BeautifulSoup and with the following code I could change the value of it to anything I wanted to

```
html_doc = requests.get("http://examplepage.com/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
tag = soup.find_all("option")[0]
tag['value']="697"
```

So now all I couldn't achieve is to load the page with the change i made with the library BeautifulSoup.

I'm kinda lost already so any help would help.

note that I can use only the following languages - python/Java/Kotlin

Comment: There are multiple solutions possible, to trigger a new request but it would be guessing - Could you provide an url?